# Runtime error '13': Type Mismatch in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code which compares a column in two worksheets. When it finds a difference, it copies the entire row to a third worksheet. It works as I want it to, except that I often (but not always) get a Type Mismatch error.

The columns I'm comparing in each sheet are helper columns formatted as text, created by first joining all of the row's contents into one helper column (via =A1&B1&C1&...), and then copying the results of that formula and pasting the VALUES into a second helper column which is also formatted as text. Then I compare the 2nd helper column of each sheet.

The values of the helper columns are long strings of letters and numbers (names,phone numbers, addresses, etc.), but since they're formatted as text, shouldn't the types be the same? The error occurs on the line:

```
Set fValue = .Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

but I don't know why. Can anyone shed some light?

```
Sub CompareRosters()
Dim lRow, lrow2 As Long
Dim fValue As Range

Sheets("RosterChanges").Range("RosterChanges").Clear
Sheets("NewRoster").Select
lRow = Range("CK1").End(xlDown).Row
lrow2 = Sheets("LastRoster").Range("CK1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each cell In Range("CK2:CK" & lRow)
    With Sheets("LastRoster").Range("CK2:CK" & lrow2)

        Set fValue = .Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If fValue Is Nothing Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("RosterChanges").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With

Next cell

End Sub
```

A clue: The Mismatch Error only occurs when the text I'm comparing exceeds 255 characters. I assume it's because a #VALUE error is returned, which in turn, triggers the Mismatch Error. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You will get that error if the `cell.Value` refers to a cell which has  formula errors(Ex: `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!`...)

Comment: While debugging this issue, I removed most of the rows from my worksheets and examined the remaining data, so I know that there are no #N/As or #ERRORs, etc. in the text that I'm comparing.

Comment: What does the cell have at the time of the error?

Comment: cell = NewCourse8-3015SU15archflapsaddle010189Another new oneSU15FLAPSADDLEARCHIBALD5033993205johnsmith@salkeiz.k12.or.usSMITHJOHN5033993205johnsmith@salkeiz.k12.or.usParentTest School Tech Ctr10M2489 PHIPPS LN.SOMETOWNOR97000YesNoarchibaldfarchibaldf0Sally Mae Sally Mae 00

Comment: and fValue = Nothing

Comment: Is this `NewCourse8-3015SU15archflapsaddle010189Another new oneSU15FLAPSADDLEARCHIBALD5033993205johnsmith@salkeiz.k12.or.usSMITHJOHN50339932‌​05johnsmith@salkeiz.k12.or.usParentTest School Tech Ctr10M2489 PHIPPS LN.SOMETOWNOR97000YesNoarchibaldfarchibaldf0Sally Mae Sally Mae 00` what you are trying to find?

Comment: Yes, that's the text in "NewRoster" that I'm trying to find in "LastRoster." If it's not there, it should paste the whole row into "RosterChanges." But the Type Mismatch error occurs on line 10 before the loop completes.